# Is the helix the unique path with constant curvature and constant torsion?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

If a path has both curvature and torsion constant why it is necessarily a helix?
How to prove it?

Comment: you mean the Frenet-Serret' system of differential equations has a unique solution?

Comment: and how to prove it has a unique solution?

Comment: I may miss a detail or two (it's been over 30 years since I read the book), but IIRC in [Lipschutz' Differential Geometry](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/211188.Schaum_s_Outline_of_Differential_Geometry) there is a theorem that curvature and torsion, as functions of the arc length, determine a 3D-curve uniquely to the extent possible, i.e. up to translation and rotation. This implies that the answer to your question is affirmative.

Answer (score 5):

If both curvature and torsion are constant, the curve is in fact a (right) *circular* helix. You can, as @JyrkiLahtonen suggests, deduce this from the Fundamental Theorem of Curve Theory: By direct computation, a circular helix has constant curvature and torsion, and the curvature and torsion functions determine the curve up to rigid motion (isometry of $\Bbb R^3$).

Alternatively, with a bit of work and cleverness, you can actually explicitly integrate the Frenet equations
\begin{align*}
T'(s) &= &\kappa N(s) \\
N'(s) &= -\kappa T(s) + &&&\tau B(s) \\
B'(s) &= &-\tau N(s)
\end{align*}
to show that $\alpha(s)$ is a right circular helix. (Hint: Show that $N''(s) = -(\kappa^2+\tau^2)N(s)$.)

A generalized helix is a curve whose tangent vector makes a constant angle with a fixed vector. Such curves are characterized by the weaker condition $\tau/\kappa = \text{constant}$.